# How to create a rule to email all users who bookmarked the author of new content?

Tags: rules, flags, notifications

I have the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) modules installed. I want other users to be notified of flagged user new content.

I made 2 rules:

1. To add the author of content to bookmarks of user:

   [image: screenshot]
2. To send an e-mail notification when bookmarked (flagged) user created new article:

   [image: screenshot]

But it sends an e-mail only to the user who created the article.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you want your workflow to be available in Rules itself. Everything is possible with some coding.http://drupal.org/node/905262

Comment: I don't have an equivalent use case, so I can only suggest. Chained tokens are available under the Send Mail action, even if they are not listed. You might try something like _To:[node:flag-bookmarks-user:mail]_, or you might have to use a php snippet to retrieve the individual user email addresses (also supported).

Answer (score 1):

As i can see in your `Actions` -  Send mail - `To:[site:current-user-mail]`. You need to create action `Send mail` and chose 'Send mail to all users of role` - and chose roles for which you want to send mail.

Comment: If i choose this, i'll send mail to all users of that role. i want to send onlt for users who bookmarked the author

Answer (score 0):

#### Mistakes in your current rules

The Rules Action in your 2nd rule is ***to send an e-mail only to `[site:current-user-mail]`***.

Since this rule is using Rules Event "After saving new content", the user who is actually saving that new content will receive that eMail. But, that user is also `[site:current-user-mail]`. So your rule "works as implemented", though that is obviously not what you want.

Moreover, you are only sending an eMail to only 1 user, instead of some type of list of users, i.e. all users who bookmarked (flagged) the author.

#### How to get it to work

To make this work you may want to give it a try to *process the results of a [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) enabled view via [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)*, whereas your rule performs 2 Rules Actions:

- Load the VBO list that you want to be processed.
- Add a loop to perform a Rules Action, for each row contained in your Views results.

Some more details about the VBO-view you'd have to create for this:

- The view should list all users who have bookmarked (flagged) the author or the newly saved node.
- It should include an appropriate filter for the userid of the node author.
- It should have exactly 1 result (row) for each user to be eMailed.
- One of the columns should be the eMail Id (I don't see other columns needed for this to work).

For more details, have a look at the tutorial "[How to process the results of a VBO enabled view via Rules?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/90)".